# ByteArray not sent from unity to C++ plugin?

Tags: c++, ios, arrays, swift, unity-game-engine

I am sending bytearray from unity to c++ plugin.

in unity

```
[DllImport ("dllplugin")]
public static extern void Method (byte[] bytes);
```

in c++ Plugin

```
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" void EXPORT_API Method(unsigned char* bytes)
```

plugin receives the bytearray but not receives the complete byte array.for example unity sending the byte array size with 17 but C++ receives the byte array size with 4.

what is the problem with bytearray? how to receive complete byte array?

Comment: Are you using `sizeof` to obtain the "array" size?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes i am using sizeof but not only the size data receiving also only 4 bytes

Comment: How is this related to Swift?